# Is it possible to remove CreatedBy field from case comment related list?

Tags: apex, visualforce, case

Can we remove CreatedBy field from case comment related list through configuration?or do we need to go for customization?if we have to go for customization please tell me the approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility except to  customize the Case Comments standard related list.

You will need to do small inline VF .The major functionalities need to replicated like New,Delete,Make Public ,Edit

Here is small pseudo code to get you keep going

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
<apex:commandButton onclick="navigate();"  value="New"/><!--Implement redirect URL to case comment page -->
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlocktable value="{!Case.CaseComments}" var="c">
 <apex:column value="{!c.Ispublished}"/>
 <apex:column value="{!c.CommentBody}"/>
</apex:pageblocktable>

</apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Replicating whole functionality for just small requirement of removing createddate from the list may be too much maintenance and must be carefully architect-ed explaining the consequences of introducing custom code into org

Comment: Thank you..How can i put createdDate and Comment body in a single row? Ex CreatedDate followed by Case Comment